# Keyset does not exist with p12 key on Shared Azure Website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-web-app-service, x509certificate2

I have a website using Google Apis in Asp.net MVC 5.

Sometimes the application throws a Keyset does not exists for an unknown reason:

Here is my code:

```
            var cert = new X509Certificate2(file, "notasecret",
                            X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | 
                            X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable |
                            X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);

            var credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
            new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(googleCredential.ClientId)
            {
                Scopes = scopes
            }.FromCertificate(cert));
            _service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "AppName"
            });
```

Any idea on how to troubleshoot this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to [load the Cert](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/10/27/using-certificates-in-azure-websites-applications)

Comment: This article does not apply for shared env

Comment: That is correct, shared environments do not enable this capability for security purposes. You may want to scale your application up to the Basic Tier. If you think this functionality should be available for Shared environments, you can always provide [feedback](http://feedback.azure.com)